# Single Sign On with Windows Identity Foundation

Tags: wif

Are there any good online resources or books regarding single sign on with WIF? I am especially interested in leveraging existing customer accounts like live.com or googlemail. I saw in some Channel 9 Videos that this should be possible but didn't stumble upon concrete examples on how to implement it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's also:

[Programming Windows Identity Foundation](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735627185)

If you want Windows Live or Google logins, you need to look at integrating WIF with Azure ACS.

Refer [Access Control Service Samples and Documentation](http://acs.codeplex.com/documentation).

Also see the how-to's etc. in the TechNet Wiki [Windows Identity Foundation (WIF) and Azure AppFabric Access Control Service (ACS) Content Map](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1546.aspx) and [Windows Identity Foundation (WIF) Content Map](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/3665.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

There are many resources available:

- Identity Training Kit ([link](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=14347))
- Claims based Identity Guide ([link](http://claimsid.codeplex.com)). The e-book for this is available [here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=19909).

Both contain theory, practice and examples of what your are trying to do.